# Internal server error. No devices found exception

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I get the following error for iOS when I tried to send push notification via MFP console

```
{
    "code": "FPWSE0009E",
    "message": "Internal server error. No devices found.",
    "productVersion": "8.0.0.00-20170220-1900"
}
```

The device is active . The is the result from the "Devices" API

{

```
    "productVersion": "8.0.0.00-20170220-1900",
    "totalListSize": 4,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "0AC11F77-A89A-4616-9085-4F6009329F3",
            "lastAccessed": "2017-07-12T16:13:56.985Z",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "deviceOs": "ios 10.2.1",
            "deviceModel": "iPhone",
            "applicationDeviceAssociations": [
                {
                    "appName": "RandstadJobsiOS",
                    "appId": "com.randstadusa.randstadjobs$ios$2.0.1",
                    "certSerialNumber": "",
                    "deviceId": "0AC11F77-A89A-4616-9085-4F6009329F3",
                    "status": "ENABLED",
                    "deviceStatus": "ACTIVE"
                }
            ]
        },
..
```

Push is working for android.

The iOS push certification is valid and will expire in 2018. I used the same cert in prod and receive push notification

Additionally,I tried to debug in Xcode and it does the following

- MFPPush.isPushSupported  -- return true
- MFPPush.initialize - return success

However, it does not execute the MFPPush.registerDevice in the code

** Update

@Vivin

When the the Subscription API is executed I get the result

```
{
    "code": "FPWSE0001E",
    "message": "Not Found - The target resource 'PushDevice' does not exist. Check the '0AC11F77-A89A-4616-9085-4F6009329F3' parameter.",
    "productVersion": "8.0.0.00-20170220-1900"
}
```

Please let me know how to debug this issue

Comment: share the console log or error that you are getting while registering the device.

Comment: There is a confusion. You mention issue during push dispatch and that the device is registered. You also mention, not being able to execute registerDevice. 
Verify the subscriptions using the REST API:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_push_device_subscriptions_get.html
Check if the subscription matches the device registration

Comment: @Vivin,  I updated the question,, The first output is a list of the device (GET Device API). When I run the subscription API I get 'PushDevice' does not exist for iOS devices.  Android device have no issue

Comment: This most likely means the subscription is not present for the device.  Can you execute the REST API I gave you . It returns the list of subscriptions. Subscriptions are made after device registration.

Comment: I get empty object for iOS   ..  {
    "devices": [],
    "productVersion": "8.0.0.00-20170220-1900"
}